# injection of environment variables with default if not set or empty

Tags: spring, tomcat, web.xml

I'd like to use something similar to the following in my web.xml:

```
<param-value>${CONF_DIR:config/files}/my.xml</param-value>
```

but I'd like to use the default not only if $CONF_DIR is not set but also when it's **empty string**.

Comment: You cannot, as that isn't supported in `web.xml`.. It is a specific Spring feature and the `web.xml` isn't processed by Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum and how would you do it in spring config files?

Comment: Just as you did here, but as mentioned the `web.xml` isn't a spring config file.

Comment: @M.Deinum,what I did seems to use the default only when $CONF_DIR is unset, but I'd like it to be used as well when it's empty-string

Comment: It will only be used if indeed the variable is not available. If it is empty then it it assumed that is the value you want to use.